mpiexec command running endlessly without output when performing distributed computing in python
I'm running the follow command:
mpiexec -n 10 -host ec2-100-26-234-17.compute-1.amazonaws.com,ec2-18-233-65-54.compute-1.amazonaws.com python test.py

The program is a basic hello world program like so:
from mpi4py import MPI

# Initialize MPI
comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = comm.Get_rank()
size = comm.Get_size()

# Print debug information
print(f"Rank {rank} of {size} is running")

# Print "Hello, World!" along with rank information
print(f"Hello, World! I'm process {rank} of {size}")

# Finalize MPI
MPI.Finalize()
print(f"Rank {rank} of {size} has finished")


The code is running endlessly.
I already made sure I can ssh between all the machines without passwords or .pem files.
The firewall are set to allow all inbound and outbound ssh connections
The code executes perfectly when trying to run on a single machine without distributed computing

Make sure there are no firewalls blocking TCP connections between the two nodes
